# Delete Output After Button is Clicked in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

So, I'd like the p id of "tip" or "tipPerPerson" to be deleted on the Clear button. I got it to work for the fields, but it only rarely works for the button. At some points, the document.getElementById works, but most of the time it does not. I do not know why or when it does clear both results because it is random, but I'd like everytime to have the fields after the button clear.

Here is the full code

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h3>A Tip Calculator</h3>
        <h5>Finding a tip amount has never been so easy</h5>
        <div id="calculator">
            <p><label for="billAmount">Bill Amount</label><input type="text" id="billAmount"
                    onkeypress="return decimalValidation(this,event);"></p>
            <p><label for="tipAmount">Tip Amount</label><input type="text" id="tipAmount"
                    onkeypress="return decimalValidation(this,event);"></p>
            <p><label for="splitCheck">People Splitting Check</label><input type="text" id="splitCheck" value=1
                    onkeypress="return decimalValidation(this,event);"></p>
            <p><input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Get Tip" onclick="getTip();"><input type="button"
                    id="clearPage" value="Clear" onclick="clearPage();"></p>
        </div>
        <p id="tip"></p>
        <p id="tipPerPerson"></p>
    </div>
</body>
```

JS

```
function clearPage() {
    document.getElementById("billAmount").value = " ";
    document.getElementById("tipAmount").value = " ";
    document.getElementById("splitCheck").value = " ";
    document.getElementById("splitCheck").value = " ";
    document.getElementById("tip").innerHTML = " ";
    document.getElementById("tipPerPerson").InnerHTML = " ";
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Minor typo - the `document.getElementById("tipPerPerson").InnerHTML = " ";` is uppercase. Should be `.innerHTML = " ";`

Comment: Thank you! I got it to work 100% percent

Answer (score 0):

You could set the display style for the output to `display: none` for example in the js code below.

I made the js set to `display: none` when clear is clicked, and then to `display: block` when the tip is recalculated.

Here is a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/SomeRandomOwl/pen/wvBLzdw) showing how the new code works

```
function getTip() {
var billAmount = Number(document.getElementById("billAmount").value);
var tipAmount = Number(document.getElementById("tipAmount").value);
var splitCheck = Number(document.getElementById("splitCheck").value);

if (billAmount == " ") {
    alert("Please enter a bill amount!");
    return false;
}

if (tipAmount == " ") {
    alert("Please enter a tip amount!");
    return false;
}

if (splitCheck == " ") {
    alert("Please enter the amount of people splitting the bill");
    return false;
}


var tipPercent = tipAmount / 100;
var tip = billAmount * tipPercent;

if (splitCheck == 1) {
    document.getElementById("tip").innerHTML = "Yor tip is $" + tip.toFixed(2);
} else {
    document.getElementById("tip").innerHTML = " ";
    document.getElementById("tipPerPerson").innerHTML = "Your tip Per Person is $" + (tip.toFixed(2) / splitCheck);
    document.getElementById("tipPerPerson").style.display = "block";
}



}


function clearPage() {
    document.getElementById("billAmount").value = " ";
    document.getElementById("tipAmount").value = " ";
    document.getElementById("splitCheck").value = " ";
    document.getElementById("splitCheck").value = " ";
    document.getElementById("tip").innerHTML = " ";
    document.getElementById("tipPerPerson").style.display = "none";
}

function decimalValidation(el, evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    var number = el.value.split('.');
    if (charCode == 8) {
        return true;
    }
    if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    //just one dot
    if (number.length > 1 && charCode == 46) {
        return false;
    }
    //get the carat position
    var caratPos = getSelectionStart(el);
    var dotPos = el.value.indexOf(".");
    if (caratPos > dotPos && dotPos > -1 && (number[1].length > 1)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function getSelectionStart(o) {
    return o.selectionStart
}
```